# Trying to print the result of kmeans() gives empty page in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, printing, k-means

I'm trying to print the result of kmeans analysis in a `shiny` app but I get an empty page without errors.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

bn<-structure(list(`Customer ID` = c("CG-12520", "CG-12520", "DV-13045", 
                                     "SO-20335", "SO-20335", "BH-11710", "BH-11710", "BH-11710", "BH-11710", 
                                     "BH-11710", "BH-11710", "BH-11710", "AA-10480", "IM-15070", "HP-14815", 
                                     "HP-14815", "PK-19075", "AG-10270", "ZD-21925", "ZD-21925", "ZD-21925", 
                                     "KB-16585", "KB-16585", "SF-20065", "EB-13870", "EH-13945", "EH-13945", 
                                     "TB-21520", "TB-21520", "TB-21520", "TB-21520", "TB-21520", "TB-21520", 
                                     "TB-21520", "MA-17560", "GH-14485", "GH-14485", "SN-20710", "SN-20710", 
                                     "SN-20710", "SN-20710", "LC-16930", "RA-19885", "ES-14080", "ON-18715", 
                                     "ON-18715", "PO-18865", "LH-16900", "LH-16900", "DP-13000"), 
                   Profit = c(41.9136, 219.582, 6.8714, -383.031, 2.5164, 14.1694, 
                              1.9656, 90.7152, 5.7825, 34.47, 85.3091999999998, 68.3568, 
                              5.4432, 132.5922, -123.858, -3.816, 13.3176, 9.98999999999999, 
                              2.4824, 16.011, 7.384, 5.0596, 15.6884, -1.0196, 240.2649, 
                              4.2224, 11.7741, -1665.0522, -7.0532, 15.525, 1.1016, 9.70919999999999, 
                              -5.715, 3.546, 9.9468, 123.4737, -147.963, 35.415, -46.9764, 
                              -15.147, 41.7564, 16.5564, 3.89399999999999, 9.56160000000001, 
                              19.7714, 8.2062, 8.47839999999999, 4.95, 6.104, 17.9634)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                       -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("pr")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$pr<-renderPrint({
    su<-bn %>% group_by(`Customer ID`) %>%
      summarize(Profit = sum(Profit))
    
    su<-su %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="Customer ID")
    km.res <- kmeans(su,2, nstart = 25)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your `renderPrint()` assigns values to several variables, but doesn't return anything at the end. Perhaps you just need `km.res` as a last line inside the function?

Comment: yes indeed thank you